# Hat menu is missing

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash

At the top, in the menu bar there was a winter hat link. But at this time there is no winter menu link.

My questions are:

- Did the Stack Overflow team disable this link, or is this any error?
- What are the benefits of getting a hat?
- Does getting hats effect any privileges?

Comment: Googling `stack overflow hats` will answer all your questions

Comment: Downvoter is hatless, repeat, hatless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winter Bash 2017 is over. The snowflake in the top bar won't return until the start of Winter Bash 2018, which will be somewhere next December. You can still visit the [Winter Bash 2017 page](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) directly, for the time being, and your second question is covered by the [FAQ](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: You're so fast...

Comment: i have update my question: Is getting hats effect any privilliges?

Comment: @BilalAhmed no. They just look cool (well, some of them do).

Comment: @Glorfindel you mention `some of them do` please provide some details

Comment: Well, one day I wore the Silencium hat and got this compliment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=41764926#41764926

Comment: @Glorfindel nice compliment...

Comment: @bilal Glorfindel meant "some of the do" look cool. Not give privileges :)

Comment: @Patrice i have got my answer with 11 down votes

Comment: @Bilal indeed. Votes on meta do not affect your rep though. But if you want less downvotes, doing just a bit of research before asking next time could help.

Answer (score 2):

Hats are a fun thing that happens in December. Once December is over they go back in the hat box for another 11 months.

The only effect hats have is on the display of your avatar. They have no effect on privileges or anything else. You might gain more privileges if you chase after some of the hats but that's a side effect and you'd have gained such privileges anyway by doing those things at any other time of year.